# TeamCity Connection Timeout

Tags: windows, mysql, teamcity

I set up a TeamCity server yesterday, and it was working fine until this morning when I restarted it. I didn't change any settings anywhere, but I keep getting this message in the teamcity-agent log on startup:

```
INFO - t.AmazonInstanceMetadataReader - Amazon is not available. Amazon EC2 integration is not active: Failed to connect to http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04. The host did not accept the connection within timeout of 7000 ms 
INFO - .agent.AmazonPropertiesUpdater - Fetched AmazonEC2 instance metadata:  
INFO - zon.agent.AmazonMetadataChecks - Amazon EC instance metadata contains no keys 
WARN - .agent.AmazonPropertiesUpdater - Fetched Amazon EC2 instance metadata does not contain required values. Probably this agent was not started inside Amazon EC2. Is proxy server used? `
```

And then this:

```
Call http://<ip address>:8111/RPC2 buildServer.registerAgent3: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect 
WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Connection to TeamCity server is probably lost. Will be trying to restore it. Take a look at logs/teamcity-agent.log for details (unless you're using custom logging).
```

When trying to connect to TeamCity, it says it can't connect to the MySQL database, and it's either offline or the connection is improperly configured - Even though the database is online, and I haven't changed anything since I first got TeamCity working. I've made sure all of the ports being used are forwarded and are allowed in my firewall.